# How to prevent the namespace generation?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I am creating an XML document with the root `Application` and a default namespace like this:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument ('http://AOR-AppML.org', 'Application', null);
```

Later I add a child element `EntityType`. The problem is that the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace is automatically generated for this element and I don't want this to happen. The code for creating and adding this element is:

```
var entityTypeNode = document.createElement('EntityType');
var entityTypeName = document.createAttribute('name');
entityTypeName.value = secondLevelProp.properties.entitytypename; // not so important
entityTypeNode.setAttributeNode(entityTypeName);
rootEl.appendChild(entityTypeNode);
```

Then I save the generated code in an XML file and the content of the file is:

```
<Application xmlns="http://AOR-AppML.org" name="SoRiN">
    <EntityType xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="EntityType"></EntityType>
</Application>
```

How can I prevent the generation of the EntityType's namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global 'document' object has a default namespace so you need to create the other elements using the 'doc' object you built.

```
var entityTypeNode = doc.createElement('EntityType');
```

That way the elements are also created in the namespace you identified.