# How to prevent empty namespace generation in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, dom, xml-serialization

What I want to do is to serialize a DOM to XML. So I create a new document

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument ('http://AOR-AppML.org', 'Application', null);
```

and I add nodes, attributes etc. This is working fine.

The problem is that I have different behaviours with `XMLSerializer` in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Chrome console output:

```
<Application xmlns="http://AOR-AppML.org" name="SoRiN"><ObjectType name="ObjectTypeName"/><Enumeration name="EnumerationName"/></Application>
```

Firefox console output (notice the **xmlns=""**):

```
<Application xmlns="http://AOR-AppML.org" name="SoRiN"><ObjectType xmlns="" name="ObjectTypeName"/><Enumeration xmlns="" name="EnumerationName"/></Application>
```

I don't want to generate that empty namespace. I've read this namespaces indicates that the corresponding elements have no default namespace (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting), but actually I want them to be in the same namespace as `Application`.

Is there any way to prevent the namespace generation in Firefox?

P.S. - yes, I've followed the advice from this post -> [How to prevent the namespace generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074652/how-to-prevent-the-namespace-generation)

**UPDATE**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g3cZK/) is a fiddle to play with.

Comment: How do you create the elements you append to the new document? According to the specifications, the answer given in the question you cited is wrong, since the method `document.createElement` does set the namespace URI to the empty one (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547).

Comment: I create the elements just as suggested in the answer of that question... what other options do I have?

Comment: I have a added a link to a fiddle to play with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the method `createElementNS`, instead of `createElement`, since the latter creates an element with empty namespace URI.

Chrome serializes incorrectly the document (if you parse the string you would get a different document, with namespace URIs wrong), Firefox does the job right. Actually [a bug was filed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106531) and marked as solved, but the problem seems to be still there.

So, simply replace `doc.createElement(yourElementName)` with `doc.createElementNS('http://AOR-AppML.org', yourElementName)`.